# .NET random assembly is modified on disk

Tags: c#, .net, dll, filesystems

One of our applications is started suddenly terminate with error "Can't load file or assembly" . After some research I found that one of DLL files used by app is changed it's size by 1-2 bytes.

After playing more with it I realized that it's related to all dll files used by application and any of them can be corrupted. We have same copy of application on another box and it runs without issues. That makes me think it's related to environment.

How can I find what process and when modifies the file? What can be reason? Does this happened to any1?

Comment: I have no idea what the reason could be since you didn't give much info to go on but I'd probably start with using Process Monitor to see what's changing the file: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have access to the computer where this is happening you can use [FileMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642) to monitor the assembly files and find out which process is changing them.

This sounds suspiciously like some sort of virus or antivirus gone wild situation.

Comment: I tried this solution, the thing is that the problem happens once in couple days. ProcMon seems has bug being shut down after certain amount of time.

Comment: Probably that they only solution to go. Thanks